# Is it possible to shorten the lever throw/stroke on a flat bar shifter (Shimano Sora 8s)?

Tags: shimano, shifter, shifting

I'm having some thumb pain with my new bike, and I think that a part of it is because the big trigger requires my thumb to go back quite a lot, forcing it to a not ergonomical move.

Is it possible to have a quick range to change the gear?
With the index finger trigger is perfect, a very short move and click, it's done!

[image]

I've tried to spin the whole gear shifter a bit to the front, but the brakes get on the way and I can't anymore.

I have a Shimano Sora.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Could you show a photo of your handlebars? You can rotate the shifters and brake levers quite freely but, obviously, they cannot overlap.

Comment: The dealer's manual does not appear to show any stroke adjustment possibility.

Comment: If you don't mind, I've edited the title to use terms that may be more recognizable. I think this is a good question. Component manufacturers have started incorporating better ergonomics in their designs. Unfortunately, they tend to start with the high end components, e.g. Dura Ace R9100 (highest road group released in 2016) shortened the downshift lever throw from the 9000 generation (2012), and Ultegra and 105 followed suit.

Comment: Please ask someone to take pictures of your hands in actual riding position, from the sides, on this bike and add them to the post. It may be that all your levers are not in the best position for you. On MTB style handlebars, the wrist should not make a sharp angle when riding and actuating the brake levers. The shifters are designed around that position and should be comfortable to use for most people. Another thing to check for is that the shifter cable is properly adjusted and routed so there is not excessive friction, so they do not require too much force to operate.

Comment: The index finger click is small because it’s releasing cable, while the thumb trigger is pulling cable. Higher end shifters have smaller lever throw, but they aren’t available for 9s and will cost you a pretty penny.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The lever action is not adjustable. And consider that if it were, you'd need to push harder over the shorter stroke to achieve the same effect.